# Binding MediaPlaybackList to ListView UWP

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Anyone tried to bind a `MediaPlaybackList` to `ListView`?This is the code :

VM

```
        public MediaPlaybackList ObservableMedia
    {
        get { return _mediaPbList; }
        set
        {
            _mediaPbList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }
```

`MediaPlaybackList` is already a collection so i don't want to use `ObservableList<MediaPlaybackList>`. Now i'd like to bind this to the ListView :

```
   <ListView x:Name="songList" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="680"  Background="{Binding }" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableMedia , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Margin="986,120,0,-80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

The problem is i dont know what property to bind in here   `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items}"/>`  to display title/artist for each `mediaPlaybackItem` in `MediaPlaybackList` ?

EDIT : Before i used `ObservableCollection<StorageFile>` ,that i add to the `ListView` and it works , but isn't it better if i have just `MediaPlaybackList` bind? This is how i use the `MediaPlaybackList` :

```
mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(item);
var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);                   
ObservableMedia.Items.Add(mediaPlaybackItem);
mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(ObservableMedia);
```

So before i'd just have `ObservableCollection<StorageFile> listOfStorageFiles` 
and add  `listOfStorageFiles.Add(item);` , then use this in the xaml and `DisplayName` , but should i really use additional list(for storageFiles) or somehow make it work with just `MediaPlaybackList` ?

Comment: MediaPlaybackList doesn't report changes like ObservableCollection, so binding to it won't make your list view update with new items. Also, you don't need Mode=TwoWay in the binding since your listview won't be pushing any items back to the MediaPlaybackList.

What I do in my app is maintain a list of MediaPlaybackItem and update it by monitoring the player events. this works better and gives you more control.

Your textblock in the data template should bind to a property in the MediaPlaybackItem object, so binding to Items is wrong.

Comment: @Rafael right now i have ObservableCollection of StorageFIles in the ViewList . So you suggesting using ObservableCollection<MediaPlaybackItem> and bind it to the ListVIew? And how can i show properties like this in the DataTemplates Text :  var itemInfo= mediaPlaybackItem.GetDisplayProperties().MusicProperties.Artist; in  xaml ? Also its problem that alot of songs for example doesnt have set Artist and Title by default - i guess only those you "borrow" instead of buying ? xD